# Extra line appears in the grid/table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to html and need some help in refining my code. I have created a grid/table and I am filling in data through a form. The table appears fine and the data is getting saved as well. However, there is an extra row appearing in the beginning of the grid. I am not sure how to get rid of it.

```html
<table class="table border nowrap dataTable no-footer">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Range</th>
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Sum of voxels</th>
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Sum of HU x # product</th>
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Mean HU</th>
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Weighting Factor</th>
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Total Volume</th>
      <th class="plex-data-table-head sorting_asc">Ca Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @{foreach record in model['data']['grid-tlevci']} @{if !helpers.isEmpty(model['data']['grid-tlevci'])}
    <tr class="grid-rows odd">
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-9670-7550'])} @{record['grid-9670-7550']} @{else} --- @{fi}

      </td>
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-4140-10'])} @{record['grid-4140-10']} @{else} --- @{fi}


      </td>
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-hm9xcc'])} @{record['grid-hm9xcc']} @{else} --- @{fi}

      </td>
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-kfjdo'])} @{record['grid-kfjdo']} @{else} --- @{fi}

      </td>
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-p4m23'])} @{record['grid-p4m23']} @{else} --- @{fi}

      </td>
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-udj32'])} @{record['grid-udj32']} @{else} --- @{fi}

      </td>
      <td>
        @{if !helpers.isEmpty(record['grid-609p6'])} @{record['grid-609p6']} @{else} --- @{fi}

      </td>

    </tr>


    @{fi} @{end}


  </tbody>

</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's coming from `@{else} --- @{fi}` so it means that the `if` conditions are failing.

Comment: So in the first record in the model, all those fields are empty. You need to check how the model is being filled in.

Comment: Or you should check if those fields are filled in in the `@{if` that controls whether the row should be shown.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your response. I have added the else condition to show --- when specific cell has no information. I will add another image to the post to show that. I will see if I can find anything else in the model.